# Run jQuery code only in a specific div

Tags: jquery

I have a homepage with the id component-homepage in the body. This page has a few animations in the footer, navigation and another element. These elements have the same name on all the other pages.

I would like to execute the jQuery code (the js file will contain more then just this code) when the elements are in the #component-homepage.

```
// This could should be on all the pages
$("nav li:last-child").addClass('last-child');

// This code should only be used when the id #component-homepage is in the body

// Homepage navigatie fadeIn + contentblok animatie
$('#content_home').hide();
$('nav').hide().fadeIn(1200, function(){
    var result = $("#content_home").outerHeight();

$('#content_home_container').css({"margin-top": -Math.abs(result), "height": (result)});

    $('#content_home').css({"margin-top": (result),"display":"block"}).animate({marginTop: '0px'},1000);
});

// Homepage navigatie animatie + url click event
$('nav a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;

    $('nav').animate({
        marginTop: '-635px'}, 
        1000,
        function(){
            window.location = href;
        });
    $('footer').fadeOut(200);
});
```

I tried wrappen the code in this:

```
$('#component-homepage').ready(function(){
    // code
});
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the code in this:

```
if ( $('#component-homepage').length ) {
    // code
}
```

the `.length` method returns the number of elements in the jQuery object, so as long as there is more than one element with this ID, this will translate to a Boolean value of `true`, and thus run the code.

**Source(s)**

[.length - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: Excellent. Excactly what I was looking for. You're line of code does the following: it checks if there's any html in the #component-homepage, if there is it runs the code, otherwise don't. Is this correct? I'll be sure to give the correct answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Not quite - it checks if there are any elements with an ID of #component-homepage, and if there is it runs the code, otherwise it doesn't - this is what you want, I think?

Comment: Take a look at [the jQuery API documentation for .length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: Hi Peter, if my answer helped you please mark it as correct. :)

Comment: Damn it! Forgot it anyway ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a context to your jQuery selectors, and they will only work within that scope:

```
$('nav a', someDOMNode)
```

If I am correct in assuming that that's what you're after...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I know I can specify a certain div to a selector. But it's bad form to repeat yourself in coding.

Comment: @Peter: If something along the lines of what Billy's answer is what you're after I misunderstood your question and my answer would not be relevant; sorry.