# Javascript functions keeps executing even after updating the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have certain content that gets updated using ajax on that Id, for example, let's suppose I have a complete main page and inside the `body` I have this code:

```
<div id="content">
<button onclick="update1()"></button>
<button onclick="update2()"></button>
</div>

    <script>
         function update1(){
                    $.ajax({
                   url:"Page1/index.html",
                   type:'GET',
                   success: function(data){
                       $('#content').html((data));
                   }
                });
         }
             function update2(){
                    $.ajax({
                   url:"Page2/index.html",
                   type:'GET',
                   success: function(data){
                       $('#content').html((data));
                   }
                });
         }
    </script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

And the `index.html` of **Page1** contains some code like this:

```
<button onclick="update1()"></button>
<button onclick="update2()"></button>
<div id="page1"> .....</div>
```

And the `index.html` of **Page2** contains some code like this:

```
<button onclick="update1()"></button>
<button onclick="update2()"></button>
<div id="page2"> .....</div>
```

And the `script.js` contains some code like this:

```
$(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "someapi",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (result) {  
                                console.log(result)
                           } 
                        });

                }, 2000);
            });
```

What I want to do is when the button is pressed to call Ajax that gets the index.html from **Page1** and puts it inside the id content, run a `script.js` this script only executes when the id ***page1*** exists, I have found this trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061702/run-jquery-code-only-in-a-specific-div), by using an if with jQuery for example `if($('#page1').length ){my sj code}` the javascript code runs only when that id exists, but unfortunately when I click the button to get the **Page2** that has another id ***page2*** that code keeps running, is there a way to stop this js code when that div is updated???

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: What do you mean by "that code keeps running"?

Comment: I have written it in the simplest way I could..

Comment: when you click on `<button onclick="update2()"></button>` it execute for infinite time ?

Comment: in your function `update2`, before ajax call ensure you remove `#page1` if it exists. Perhaps `if($('#page1').length ){$('#page1').remove();}`

Comment: I mean the script.js has a code that runs every 2 seconds, using setInterval..

Comment: `setInterval()` is not mentioned at OP. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you paste running code?

Comment: I mean this: $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {...},2000})

Comment: js/script.js    what is in it

Comment: I added what is inside the script.js, it's like when it runs it won't stop, is there a way to stop it

Comment: why you are using setInterval?   obviously it will runs continously

Comment: Because I need to make some requests on that Id and update when something changes...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155832/discussion-between-programmer-man-and-krishnar).

Comment: @ProgrammerMan  check my solution

Comment: @ProgrammerMan  check below answers. I given solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is not stopping because the interval will not stop firing unless you clear it, using `clearInterval()` function.

just put all your JS code in one file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var the_interval = setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "someapi",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        }
    });

}, 2000);

function stopTheInterval(){
    clearInterval(the_interval);
}

function update1(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"Page1/index.html",
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html((data));
        }
    });
}

function update2(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"Page2/index.html",
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html((data));
            stopTheInterval(); // we stop the first interval
        }
    });
}});
```

what I did here is saved the interval number in a variable, and created a new function to clear it.
next, all I did was put my new function in your update2() function, so once I get the data back I clear the interval and stop the repeating function.

Comment: Thank you this is more close to the solution of my problem.

Comment: No problem hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

script.js
**dont use setInterval.**

```
function some_function(){ 
  $.ajax({
      url: "someapi",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {  
          console.log(result)
     } 
  });  
}
```

*And call above function in update1.because you want it only when page1 updated*

```
<script>
  function update1(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"Page1/index.html",
      type:'GET',
      success: function(data){
        $('#content').html((data));
        some_function()       // call function here
      }
    });
  }

function update2(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"Page2/index.html",
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
      $('#content').html((data));
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: The setInterval is everything on my app I need to check continuously for changes without it, nothing is going to work, I provided only examples If I put my code which is more than 2000 lines and confidential it's not worth it, thank you all, I will figure out something.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `update1().stop()`
in starting of `update2` function